# Can't access different JSP files from index with servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm trying out to set up a simple web app with TomCat, there is a servlet that's supposed to link my index page with a 2 buttons pointing at 2 different JSP.

The thing it does is when I click on those buttons it doesn't change the page, it only puts the name of the Servlet "request" (sorry don't really know the exact term).

Also when I tried to access directly by typing for example localhost:8080/reunion.jsp to access the pages directly it stays on index as if it's the only page there even if it looks like it's trying to load another page.

Here is the code of the Servlet and Index.

```
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init(config);
        sc = this.getServletContext();
    }

    public Servlet(){
        super();
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String op = request.getParameter("operation");

        if (op.equalsIgnoreCase("cv")){
            this.versPersonne(request, response);
        }
        if (op.equalsIgnoreCase("reunion")){
            this.versReunion(request, response);
        }

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    }

    private void versReunion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/reunion.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    private void versPersonne(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/cv.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }


}
```

---

Here is the index

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>$Title$</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="Servlet?operation=cv" method="post">
  <br><input type=submit value="Page personne"/>
</form>

<form action="Servlet?operation=reunion" method="post">
  <br><input type=submit value="Page réunion"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

And just in case here is the web.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My JSP files are all in the web folder.

I looked really hard for an answer and tried many different things and configurations but can't seem to find an answer.

I do think the problem lies with the servlet configuration somehow but can't really find the answer.

UPDATE : Thanks to the first answers I deleted the XML file and updated the DoGet Method.
At this point the web app does try to switch pages but it throws me a 500 Error Exception telling me that it failed to instantiate the servlet here is the log :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Erreur à l'instantiation de la classe servlet [com.example.Servlet]
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

And the root cause :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
com.example.Servlet.<init>(Servlet.java:15)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

This is the project structure :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr1PL.jpg

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `web.xml` file is the culprit.

You want to use your servlet as `/Servlet`, in the `WebServlet` annotation, but at the same time, the xml file maps `index.jsp` to **any URL** with `/*`.

As you have declared the mapping with the `WebServlet` annotation, and as `index.jsp` is the default page, just remove the mapping frow `web.xml` and strip it down to:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

</web-app>
```

Or even simplier remove the web.xml file since it does not contain anything longer.

---

You have another error in your servlet code: you try to initialize the ServletContext at creation time which you should not. It should be:

```
@WebServlet("/Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private ServletContext sc;    // delay initialization to init

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init(config);
        sc = this.getServletContext();
    }
```

But in fact you have no reason to store a reference to the ServletContext. You use it only to get a `RequestDispatcher` when you could simply get it from the `Request`:

```
private void versReunion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/reunion.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

That's all. Do the same in `versPersonne` and you can remove any line refering to `sc`...

Comment: Yes , indeed I noticed that a bit after and deleted it , now it does change something by giving me a 500 Error exception telling me that it was impossible to instantiate the servlet.

Comment: @user9999270: Hmm, there is no reason for that. Try to stop the Tomcat server and restart it.

Comment: I just did , restarted everything even the computer. Still the same problem. I'm starting to think that there is a problem with the IDE configuration but I didn't change a lot of stuff (working on Intellij btw)

Comment: Ok, I had not used the servlet context in my test on only copied the `doPost` method. See my edit...

Comment: Thank you ! It worked I'll keep that in mind for the future , the weird part is that people around me working on the same assignment managed to make it work on eclipse with the same code. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

call method doPost(request,response); inside doGet method as shown below, that should fix your issue.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    doPost(request, response);

}
```

also in Index.jsp you have specified form action as `"Servlet?operation=reunion"`
change that to `"/Servlet?operation=reunion"`

similarly change `"Servlet?operation=cv"` to `"/Servlet?operation=cv"`

Comment: Thanks for you answer , I did both the things you suggested and it did change something, now it gives me an Error 500  when I click on either button telling me that it failed to instantiate the Servlet , and when I try again after getting that Error it gives me a 404 for not found.

Comment: I'm gonna update it in the first post since it's too long to answer here

Comment: Yes, Please update also can you share screenshot of your project file structure?

Comment: It did work now like Serge said I had an issue with using my Server Context, thanks for you time, have a good day

Comment: Also try to use `init()` method instead of `init(ServletConfig config)`, you don't have to call `super.init(config)` when calling `init()`